# Java, exception handling and closing streams with try, finally

Tags: java, stream

I just wanted to see if there was a better way I should be handling this. My understanding of streams is that as long as you close a stream, any streams encapsulated within it will be closed which is why I only close TarArchiveOutputStream in finally. If I get FileNotFound on the rawDir or archiveDir I want to log it, otherwise anything else I want to throw.

```
public static void createTarGzOfDirectory(File rawDir, File archiveFile) throws IOException {
    FileOutputStream fOut = null;
    BufferedOutputStream bOut = null;
    GzipCompressorOutputStream gzOut = null;
    TarArchiveOutputStream tOut = null;
    try {
        fOut = new FileOutputStream(archiveFile);
        bOut = new BufferedOutputStream(fOut);
        gzOut = new GzipCompressorOutputStream(bOut);
        tOut = new TarArchiveOutputStream(gzOut);
        addFileToTarGz(tOut, rawDir, "");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        log.error("File not found: " + e);
    } finally {
        if(tOut != null) {
            tOut.finish();
            tOut.close();
        }
    }
```

Any other considerations or thoughts on improving things?

Comment: Why do you think you want to call 'finish'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My understanding of streams is that as long as you close a stream, any streams encapsulated within it will be closed ...

That is correct.

However, your code is (effectively) assuming that if `tOut` is `null`, then none of the other streams in the chain have been created.  That's a somewhat dodgy assumption.  Consider this sequence:

1. The `FileOutputStream` is created and is assigned to `fOut`.
2. The `BufferedOutputStream` is created and is assigned to `bOut`.
3. The `GzipCompressorOutputStream` constructor throws an exception or error.  (Maybe the heap is full ...).
4. The `catch` is skipped ... wrong exception.
5. The `finally` checks `tOut`, finds it is `null`, and does nothing.

Net result: we've leaked the file descriptor / channel held by the `FileOUtputStream`.

The key to getting this example (absolutely) right is to understand which of those stream objects holds the critical resources, and ensuring that THAT stream gets closed.  The other streams that don't hold resources don't have to be closed.

```
} finally {
    if (fOut != null) {
        fOut.close();
    }
}
```

The other point is that you need to move the `tOut.finish()` call into the `try` block after the `addFileToTarGz` call.

- If the `addFileToTarGz` call throws an exception, or if you don't get that far, the `finish` call is a waste of time.
- The `finish` call will attempt to write the index to the archive, and THAT could throw an IOException.  If this happens in the `finally` block, then any following code in the finally block to close the stream chain won't get executed ... and a file descriptor will be leaked.

Comment: The check for null adds complexity for no reason. Initialize `fOut` at declaration, before `try`.

Comment: @erikson - I'm aware of that.  However, if you do that you'll need another enclosing try-catch to report the FileNotFound exception.  My answer is focussing on is CORRECTNESS, not on the most elegant solution to the problem.

Comment: Usually when exceptions are handled at this level, they are handled incorrectly. Since the method throws `IOException`, it would be correct not to `catch` anything. It's not really about " elegance"; it's easier to make simpler code correct.

Comment: When people try to use nulls to avoid two try statements (or the execute around idiom) they typically mess it up. The number of times I had to point out bugs in the CERT Java secure coding thing. Fortunately the current version of Java SE has try-wth-resource. The only significant benefit of try-with-resource is that it should get rid of this null dancing.

Comment: @erickson - You are correct.  However, as I said, I'm trying to point out what is incorrect about the OP's code, not provide the most elegant / demonstrably correct rewrite of his code.  If you want to do that, please submit your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Although it would look ugly and is,maybe, unlikely to be the case, you should close them all in cascade. Yes, if you close the TarArchiveOutputStream, it is supposed to close the underlyning streams. But, depending on the implementation, it may not always be the case. Moreover, and probably mainly, if one of the intermediate constructors throw an exception, tOut will be null, but the other ones may not be. Meaning that your streams are opened but your did not close any.

Answer (score 0):

You could chain all your constructors together like so:

```
    tOut = new TarArchiveOutputStream(new GzipCompressorOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(archiveFile))));
```

And save yourself 6 lines of initialization and 3 local variables for debugging. Not everyone likes chaining things that way - I personally find it more readable but the rest of your team may prefer it your way.

As far as closing the stream, it looks correct to me.

Comment: What happens if GzipCOmpressorOutpuStream constructor throws an exception? how do you close the other ones?

Comment: @GuillaumePolet - in theory that is a leak.  In practice, you have to consider what might cause an exception to be thrown there, and decide whether that is *likely* to happen repeatedly.

Comment: @StephenC Agreed. But even if it can happen only a few times, I think you should foresee those cases and close the stream anyway. If no exceptions can be thrown by any of the intermediate constructors, of course it's just a waste of time

Comment: It only needs to happen once to prevent the application in which it appears from reloading correctly. If you want to chain intermediate constructors, alright, but don't lose your reference to the base stream.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet - I'm not disagreeing with you.  I'm just saying that in practice, some leaks are not problematic.  In this case, the class is not a standard Java class, so we don't know what exceptions might be possible.  But if it is just Error subclasses, then the correct way to handle the problem is to pull the plug on the JVM ... which renders any leaks moot.  And the application should (maybe) treat unexpected unchecked exceptions the same way.

Comment: I find it difficult to understand (not just read - who cares about just reading?) code enough already without having to worry about what exceptions might be cause, how likely that is, what will happen locally if they are and what will happen to whatever application this code makes its into.